# Custom cameraView stretched for api level >21

Tags: android, camera-view

I am getting CameraView Streatch issue in api >21

the issue is cameraView area preview is small than area captured

Example: cameraView Preview is -----  after takePicture -------- . Why this area is not preview while camera open?

```
public CameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        if (isInEditMode()){
            mCallbacks = null;
            mDisplayOrientationDetector = null;
            return;
        }
        // Internal setup
        final PreviewImpl preview = createPreviewImpl(context);
        mCallbacks = new CallbackBridge();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            mImpl = new Camera1(mCallbacks, preview);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            mImpl = new Camera2(mCallbacks, preview, context);
        } else {
            mImpl = new Camera2Api23(mCallbacks, preview, context);
        }
        // Attributes
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CameraView, defStyleAttr,
                R.style.Widget_CameraView);
        mAdjustViewBounds = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CameraView_android_adjustViewBounds, false);
        setFacing(a.getInt(R.styleable.CameraView_facing, FACING_BACK));
        String aspectRatio = a.getString(R.styleable.CameraView_aspectRatio);
        if (aspectRatio != null) {
            setAspectRatio(AspectRatio.parse(aspectRatio));
        } else {
            setAspectRatio(Constants.DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO);
        }
        setAutoFocus(a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CameraView_autoFocus, true));
        setFlash(a.getInt(R.styleable.CameraView_flash, Constants.FLASH_AUTO));
        a.recycle();
        // Display orientation detector
        mDisplayOrientationDetector = new DisplayOrientationDetector(context) {
            @Override
            public void onDisplayOrientationChanged(int displayOrientation) {
                mImpl.setDisplayOrientation(displayOrientation);
            }
        };
    }

    @NonNull
    private PreviewImpl createPreviewImpl(Context context) {
        if (preview == null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {
                preview = new SurfaceViewPreview(context, this);
            } else {
                preview = new TextureViewPreview(context, this);
            }
        }
        return preview;
    }
```

Comment: Add some code, so it'll be easier to check.

Comment: added. please tell me the issue if new api has changed implementation then give the link